# How to specify date and duration in one expression

Tags: java, intervals, iso8601

I am trying to find notation for periodic event in ISO8601 format.
Can it be done as one expression?

For example, event starting at March 31 2017 at 17:25 with periodicity 1 hour:

```
2017-03-31T17:25:00Z/PT1H
```

Trying to parse this expression to `Duration` in Java:

```
java.time.Duration d = java.time.Duration.parse("2017-03-31T17:25:00Z/PT1H");
```

results in exception.

Comment: You should also understand that a temporal amount like `java.time.Duration` is NOT an interval because the anchor on instant timeline is missing (no defined start and end). Therefore this type can at best only be used to parse the second component "PT1H", not more.

Answer (score 2):

In Iso-8601, the expression "2017-03-31T17:25:00Z/PT1H" is not a recurrent interval but just a normal instant/moment-interval. If you look for recurrent intervals then you have to prefix it with "Rn/" where "n" is a positive integer (optional). Standard Java has no support for intervals so you have to either code your own workaround with string processing and partial parsing or you use a 3rd-party library like my one ([Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J)):

```
MomentInterval interval = MomentInterval.parseISO("2017-03-31T17:25:00Z/PT1H");
System.out.println(interval); // [2017-03-31T17:25:00Z/2017-03-31T18:25:00Z)
```

See also the [Javadoc](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/MomentInterval.html#parseISO-java.lang.String-) for moment intervals. For recurrent intervals please have a look at this class [IsoRecurrence](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IsoRecurrence.html).

Interoperability note: You can easily convert the `Moment`-components to `java.time.Instant` via the method `toTemporalAccessor()`.